# Properties of a martrix which is a linear transformation on a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is a multiple choice question which had four options and in the answer booklet it gives out of many others one particular answer regarding which I have some doubts. The question is as follows:
"Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers, $\mathbf{}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{ℝ^{3×3}} $ be the
matrix corresponding to the projection on to the subspace ." One of the correct answers is given as $M^2=M$. But my doubt is what if $\mathbf{U} = \mathbb{R^3}$ since U is a subspace, so it can have the same dimension as $\mathbb{R^3}$ by definition. And we can have $$M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
That is, $M(e1) = e3$, $M(e2) = e1$ and $M(e3) = e2$, where $(e1,e2,e3)$ is the standard basis. So, in this case we won't have $M^2=M$ since $M^2(e1) = e2$ and so on. Based on the above given question am I correct or missing something?

Comment: Indentity is the only projection from $\mathbb R^{3}$ onto  $\mathbb R^{3}$. Projections leave all the elements of the range fixed.

Comment: Isn't every linear transformation is kind of a projection? Consider it is a mapping from same space onto itself @geetha290krm

Comment: No. If $U=\mathbb R^3$ you don't want a vector $v\in U$ to change when you project it "onto" $U\,.$ BTW. Regardless of what $U$ is, every projection must have this property. Therefore $M^2=M\,.$

Comment: Thanks @KurtG. for your insights. I think I misunderstood the question. They are asking for particularly "projection matrices" irrespective of $\mathbf{U}$, only condition is it has to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: Except for the trivial $U=\{0\}$ there are only three types of interesting subspaces of $\mathbb R^3\,.$ To make this a fruitful exercise can you write down the projection matrix $M$ in each of the three cases? You can choose the notation for $U$ freely.

Comment: My favorite projection matrix is the zero matrix. Another easy examples are the identity matrix with a diagonal element switched to zero. Given a unit column vector $u$ then $P=uu^T$ is also a projection matrix. If you uniformly choose random elements for the matrix the probability that it will be a projection is zero so most matrices will not be projections.